# Customize Sharepoint Left Navigation Links

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, menu, left-navigation

We're looking to have a feature where the left navigation bar shows the request type together with the number of Pending/Completed requests, like so:

Completed (20)

Pending (5)

---

Something like that. Can we do this in Sharepoint where we can append the number on the link name?

Comment: You will need to add more details to your question. What "requests" are you looking to show? Are they from a list, a workflow, a task?